# Xamarin Forms: Entry Math Fraction

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, fractions

I'm trying to create a Entry that displays an `Entry` in a fraction style. I really need to do in a way that it gets aligned (numerator, horizontal line below and the denominator below) as the [image](https://images.twinkl.co.uk/tw1n/image/private/t_630/u/ux/screen-shot-2020-04-01-at-15.22.21_ver_1.png) shows.

The fraction can be in the middle of the formula, so I can't just set `Grid.Row` to it, because it gets unaligned.

Any ideas?

Comment: you probably need to use SkiaSharp, or look into the native Text support offered by each platform.  This sounds like a very non-trivial problem to solve

Comment: @Jason yes, I was thinking about SkiaSharp, I was trying to use something from Xamarin Essentials or some native package or a package that only do fractions, but none of that is for Entries. Probably I will do with SkiaSharp. Thanks for now.

Comment: How will the user interact with this Entry? Do they type `3/9`, and then the entry converts that into the style shown? Are you planning on expanding this to enter more complicated formulas?  If not, consider having two Entries, for numerator and divisor.

Comment: Also consider an alternative approach, where they edit a "stringified" version of the formula in a text box ("3/9"), and below it, as a separate box, you show the fancy formula as an image that you draw with SkiaSharp.

Comment: Or draw that separate box using [Xamarin Forms Shapes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/shapes/) inside an [AbsoluteLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/absolutelayout).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply create your own custom control like this without using any third party library:

**FractionEntryControl XAML code**

```
<ContentView
    x:Class="SampleApp.Controls.FractionEntryControl"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Name="this">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Frame
                Padding="20"
                BorderColor="DodgerBlue"
                CornerRadius="10">
                <StackLayout Spacing="0">
                    <Entry Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference this}, Path=NumeratorText}" WidthRequest="10" />
                    <BoxView BackgroundColor="Black" HeightRequest="1" />
                    <Entry Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference this}, Path=DenominatorText}" WidthRequest="10" />
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

**FractionEntryControl Code behind:**

```
public partial class FractionEntryControl : ContentView
{
    public FractionEntryControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static BindableProperty NumeratorTextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(NumeratorText), typeof(string),
            typeof(FractionEntryControl), defaultValue: string.Empty);

    public string NumeratorText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(NumeratorTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NumeratorTextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static BindableProperty DenominatorTextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(DenominatorText), typeof(string),
            typeof(FractionEntryControl), defaultValue: string.Empty);

    public string DenominatorText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(DenominatorTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DenominatorTextProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

**Android Entry Renderer for removing default underline:**

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
{
     base.OnElementChanged(e);
     if (Control != null)
     {
         Control.Background = new ColorDrawable(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
         Control.Gravity = GravityFlags.CenterHorizontal;   
     }
}
```

**Use this control in your View:**

```
<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
     <control:FractionEntryControl DenominatorText="20" NumeratorText="10" />
</StackLayout>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Ok, but where I put this `Android Entry Renderer for removing default underline`? I tried to put in MainActivity.cs on Android but I can't override it. My project is Xamarin Forms.

Comment: @Que44 First understand the concept of Renderers in Xamarin forms: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/

Comment: Thanks, it worked.